# Managing Lifetime Scopes with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

Context: Owin (self-host) + WebApi + UseAutofacMiddleware + UseAutofacWebApi

What I'm trying to do is:

Register an `ILog` instance in the app startup container.

For each request, register a new `ILog` instance wrapping the "root" instance, so that each middleware and/or per-request services can use it.

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(log).As<ILog>();
containerBuilder.Register(ctx => {
    var rootLog = ctx.Resolve<ILog>();
    return new PrependStringLog(rootLog, "request: ");
}).InstancePerRequest();
```

However, Autofac complains about circular dependencies when instancing middleware having an `ILog` in their constructors.

If I name the "root log", and resolve with the given name, everything works as expected.

```
containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(log)
                .Named("root", typeof(ILog));
containerBuilder.Register(ctx => {
    var rootLog = ctx.ResolveNamed<ILog>("root");
    return new PrependStringLog(rootLog, "request: ");
}).InstancePerRequest();
```

Am I forced to use a named instance to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Autofac* uses the latest registered service when a component request for a service.

In your  case, the latest `ILog` registered is a lambda expression :

```
containerBuilder.Register(ctx => {
    var rootLog = ctx.Resolve<ILog>();
    return new PrependStringLog(rootLog, "request: ");
}).InstancePerRequest();
```

This lambda expression request an `ILog` which is what *Autofac* is trying to build : that's why it detects a circular dependency.

The easiest way to avoid the circular dependency is to make your registration not rely on itself. This is what you do by resolving a named `ILog` and this is the solution I recommend.

In your case, you can also directly use the root log without resolving it :

```
containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(rootLog).As<ILog>();
containerBuilder.Register(ctx => {
    return new PrependStringLog(rootLog, "request: ");
}).InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: In my mind, having different lifetime scopes was enough to ease the resolution mechanism. After all, the per-request scope has a parent scope in which there is already a perfectly valid ILog instance, and that would be a circular dependency. That being said, I understand your reasoning, I'll keep using named instances.